# How to implement "Quick Switch Editor" in an UI page of Form Editor?

Tags: java, eclipse

There is an editor called "Quick Switch Editor" to show the list of opened files in eclipse and it provides filtering option also to find out the required file from the huge file list.

I have created a Form Editor for my application and i want the same behavior in one of the UI pages of the Form Editor. When the icon which is defined for "Show List" is clicked in the UI page, i want to show a list of files from the project. And the required file can be selected and populated into the UI page.

So which class is responsible to implement this "Quick Switch Editor"? If i know the class, then i can implement the same for my UI page.

Or is any other editor supports the same behavior, available in eclipse?

Comment: if you want to check the list of `opened files in eclipse in editor` click `ctrl+shift+E`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Quick Switch Editor menu has command id `org.eclipse.ui.window.openEditorDropDown` which is handled by the `org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbookEditorsHandler` handler.

The handler uses the current stack renderer to show the dialog, for the SWT renderer the dialog is `org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt.BasicPartList`.

I not sure looking at that dialog will be all that useful since it uses a lot of e4 code. The dialog is just using a `TableViewer` with a filter and a `Text` control to define the filter.